# Steady Euler flows with compact support?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fluid-dynamics

What is known about (3D) steady incompressible Euler flows  with compact support?

(Looking for  results   in a field you are not familiar with sure is tough. 
I  had a   hope  to find clues  starting from the famous  paper  of 
V. Scheﬀer about  a flow  with compact support in space-time, and from 
works on vortex rings I could find, but in both cases ended up empty handed. 
This problem was considered by some, I presume? )

Comment: Do you mean *incompressible* flows ?

Comment: In case anyone is curious, they exist  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00039-019-00476-6

Answer (score 2):

According to the following paper, it is an open problem whether such solutions exist:
N. Nadirashvili, Liouville theorem for Beltrami flow, Geometric and Functional Analysis 24 (2014), 916-921.

Comment: Thank you. I have two problems with this source though: 1. There is no reference at all. 2.  The space is not mentioned   (no solution even in $L^2$?)

Comment: @AlexGavrilov: How would you give a reference to substantiate that a problem is open? I mean, other than by citing someone else who has made the same statement.

Comment: I simply suspect that the problem is open but very obscure and not interesting to anyone besides a couple of experts. Actually, I had plans to try and construct an example, but given the response I am about to change my mind.